# Scrollbar horizontal sendo rolada pela scrollbar vertical

Tags: html, css, html5

Estou fazendo um pequeno teste com a scrollbar do Chrome Canary 74 no Android.

Li muito a respeito, mas não obtive resultados para o dispositivo mobile, e como não tenho pc, eu uso o Aide Web para programar.

No meu projeto, há apenas dois arquivos, um css e o outro html.

Parece spam de h, mas não é:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #000; 
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

html,body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Quando eu dou um RUN no projeto, fica basicsmente deste modo:

[Inicio]

[image: Imagem da primeira parte da execução projeto]

[Fim]

[image: Imagem da segunda parte da execução projeto]

Comment: Cara sua dúvida não ficou muito clara, o seu problema é esse scroll horizontal que não deveria aparecer a barra já que está uma letra abaixo da outra? Qual é de fato o seu problema?

Comment: Não, ela deve aparecer, mas ele fica abaixo das letras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o seu problema é que vc não colocou uma altura determinada no `html` e `body`, eu usei `height: 100vh;` nesse exepmplo, pode ser que isso deixe a barra no lugar esperado.

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #f00;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #000; 
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}

html,body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width">
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
      h<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: O problema é que, no Android,  quando remove qualquar um deles, a scrollbar não aparece. Acabei de tentar

Comment: @EduardoProcópioGomez fiz uma edição colocando uma altura determinada de 100vh no HTML e Body, testa ai pra ver se com o valor declarado funciona como vc  espera

Comment: Obrigado!! Acho que aprendi o basico do stack overflow

Comment: @EduardoProcópioGomez é usando que a gente aprende, sua pergunta foi bem feita, só que apenas com texto é difícil passar algumas ideia, então temos que caprichar nos detalhes, mas vc está no caminho. Abs e bom fim de ano!